# Cloud-config-auto install- root password

Tags: cloud-init

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.4 with cloud init, I would like to configure password for root so I tried this option but it didn't works. (vmware machine the login its form the consle)

```
UPDATE-
```

This option wroks for me. (Thanks Andrew Lowther)

```
user-data:
    chpasswd:
      list: |
      expire: false
      list:
        - root:$6$bababa   

                                                                                                            


#cloud-config
    autoinstall:
      version: 1
      apt:
        disable_components: []
        geoip: true
        preserve_sources_list: false
        primary:
        - arches:
          - amd64
          - i386
          uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
        - arches:
          - default
          uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
      identity:
        hostname: my-hostname
        password: $6$baagagagagaa$ewAe9SRZlS2q6yxYtvyJ0u.Lu4l6pgSf5uisgagajlOVTjBfuBb4QIQekfaToA1DtKAUCjoiiAEyc5VYj26uS1
        realname: scadmin
        username: scadmin
      user-data:
        chpasswd:
          expire: false
          list:
            - root: $6$2mzNTlBmwfafad$0liKgagaoGfafafblalblalJQAbloalblalaFmw2m9fNXHHSZvw3zSfYH/sAA2P/kcTG8wruhLI6WWWzFaMiTEblHnfF8hQQPtxRs.
      kernel:
        package: linux-generic
      keyboard:
        layout: us
        toggle: null
        variant: ''
      locale: en_US.UTF-8
      network:
        network:
          version: 2
          ethernets:
            ens160:
              dhcp4: yes
              dhcp-identifier: mac
      ssh:
        allow-pw: true
        authorized-keys: []
        install-server: true
      storage:
        config:
        - ptable: gpt
          path: /dev/sda
          wipe: superblock-recursive
          preserve: false
          name: ''
          grub_device: true
          type: disk
          id: disk-sda
        - device: disk-sda
          size: 1048576
          flag: bios_grub
          number: 1
          preserve: false
          grub_device: false
          type: partition
          id: partition-0
        - device: disk-sda
          size: 30064771072
          wipe: superblock
          flag: ''
          number: 2
          preserve: false
          grub_device: false
          type: partition
          id: partition-1
        - name: vg0
          devices:
          - partition-1
          preserve: false
          type: lvm_volgroup
          id: lvm_volgroup-0
        - device: disk-sda
          size: 2144337920
          wipe: superblock
          flag: ''
          number: 3
          preserve: false
          grub_device: false
          type: partition
          id: partition-3
        - fstype: ext4
          volume: partition-3
          preserve: false
          type: format
          id: format-0
        - name: lv-swap
          volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
          size: 4294967296B
          wipe: superblock
          preserve: false
          type: lvm_partition
          id: lvm_partition-0
        - name: lv-root
          volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
          size: 25765609472B
          wipe: superblock
          preserve: false
          type: lvm_partition
          id: lvm_partition-1
        - fstype: ext4
          volume: lvm_partition-1
          preserve: false
          type: format
          id: format-3
        - path: /
          device: format-3
          type: mount
          id: mount-3
        - fstype: swap
          volume: lvm_partition-0
          preserve: false
          type: format
          id: format-4
        - path: ''
          device: format-4
          type: mount
          id: mount-4
        - path: /boot
          device: format-0
          type: mount
          id: mount-0
      updates: security
      packages:
        - open-vm-tools
      late-commands:
        - |
          cat <<EOF > /target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/80_my.cfg
          hostname: $(openssl rand -hex 3)
          manage_etc_hosts: true
          preserve_hostname: false
          EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `identity` section then the `users` section does not get used.  The `users` key also goes under the `user-data` key.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1385096/376778

You don't need to create the `root` user.  You just need to set its password.  I've used this partial `user-data` configuration to set the root password.  This should work for local logins (e.g. vmware console) but additional configuration would be needed to allow remote logins (e.g. ssh).

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  user-data:
    chpasswd:
      expire: false
      list:
        - root:$6$REDACTED
```

Comment: user-data:
    chpasswd:
      list: |
      expire: false
      list:
        - root:$6$bababa