# how to enable root user by default in autoinstall user data

Tags: system-installation, root, automation, user-data, autoinstall

in my product, i need to enable root user by default in autoinstall user-data file

Expectation: root user login by default post installation

i followed the below,

```
version: 1
user-data:
    disable_root: false
identity:
    hostname: hostname
    username: root
    password: $6$AYtLXyyVZAea2aLJ$UQxW1cz2vWWNn.17.3QYH5TxZqIMGoLJCpqbBTfClhUKxqouYn7/Yc5Jsq.bCeK0VDLPxbL6xzfJ0xqTb6MLk.
```

Do we need to edit target /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add PermitRootLogin to yes?

Any other method it will be helpful

Comment: The "identity" is for creating a normal user. Have you tried the "authorized-keys" in the SSH part ?

Comment: "in my product, i need to enable root user by default.". In this year of 2023, there is NO excuse for such bad system design. No security aware person will install your "product". Read `man sudo sudoers` and redesign.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1419491/376778