# Update/set root password in auto-install

Tags: password, root, autoinstall

I need to set the root password in the autoinstall as it allows me to check the system by logging into the console after installation. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, and I have the following:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: root
    lock_passwd: false
    hashed_passwd: <output from mkpasswd --method=SHA-512>
```

I even tried using `late-commands` `run-command` sections with chpasswd commands like the following, but it didn't work

```
chroot /target sh -c 'echo "root:<output from mkpasswd --method=SHA-512>" | /usr/sbin/chpasswd -e'
```

Is it possible to change the root password using auto-install? If so, I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591885/how-do-i-set-a-custom-password-with-cloud-init-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

The `user-data` section can be used.  With this option *cloud-init* will set the root password during first boot.  Be aware that the root password hash will be in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` on the installed system.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  user-data:
    chpasswd:
      expire: false
      list:
        - root:$6$REDACTED
```

Alternatively you can use `late-commands`.  This will set the password during the install.  Be aware the root password hash will be in the installer logs in `/var/log/installer` on the installed system.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      echo 'root:$6$REDACTED' | /usr/sbin/chroot /target chpasswd -e
```

The `chroot` needs to be after the pipe so the proper command is chrooted.

**note**

You can **not** use the *cloud-init* `users` module to set the password for `root` because the `root` user exists.  The [config schema documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#users-and-groups) explicitly states

> passwd: ... This will NOT be applied if the user already exists

**see also**

- [Cloud-config-auto install- root password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419481/cloud-config-auto-install-root-password/1419491#1419491)
- [Ubuntu Server 20.04 cloud-config adding user does nothing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385066/ubuntu-server-20-04-cloud-config-adding-user-does-nothing/1385096#1385096)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can see the root password hash in the /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg file on the installed system but am unable to login. ```datasource:
  None:
    metadata:
      instance-id: b21ac651-8e44-4197-bd96-9aced02090f0
    userdata_raw: "#cloud-config\ngrowpart:\n  mode: 'off'\nlocale: en_US.UTF-8\n\
      preserve_hostname: true\nresize_rootfs: false\nssh_pwauth: false\nusers:\n-\
      \ gecos: root\n  groups: adm,cdrom,dip,lxd,plugdev,sudo\n  lock_passwd: false\n\
      \  name: root\n  passwd: $6$REDACTED\n\```

Comment: @Prasad Can you confirm you are trying to login by console (and not by ssh)?  Can you confirm you replaced `$6$REDACTED` with your own password hash?  If you are able to see the `99-installer.cfg` file contents then you can also check `/etc/shadow` to see if it is correct and the logs to see if they indicate why the login failed.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! I am logging in to the console and have replaced `$6$REDACTED` with the actual hash. Moreover, I can set the password correctly if I use the same hash using `chpasswd -e` after the installation. The strange thing is that I am not seeing the password hash in `/etc/shadow` it's `*` instead of the hash, which I believe means the password is locked despite the auto-install configuration intended to set and activate it. It gets replaced with the hash if I set it with `chpasswd -e` after logging in to the system post installation. Any pointers on what could be wrong here?

Comment: @Prasad It looks like you are using the cloud-init `users` module instead of `chpasswd`.  I updated the answer with a note why this will not work.